# Removing surface rust from my Eggbeater pedals?

Tags: maintenance, pedals, rust

So I did a couple of wet rides last month, and I guess I didn't dry the pedals as well as I should have.  I have Crank Brothers Eggbeater pedals, and I noticed a bit of surface rust on them that I'd like to remove.  What are my options, considering that I can't really disassemble the pedals, and they have a large number of surfaces that are hard to get to?

Comment: Where is the rust located?  I've had a Candy-SL pedal fail near the base of one of the clips so make sure that area isn't weakened from corrosion.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably best with a metal brush the consistency of the items recommnded in the question below. Ultimately it's gonna happen though so all we can do is our best to dry up and clean up items. At some point they need replacing. A bit of light oil on the pedal the night before a wet ride might help keep of the rust by not letting water in. Of course it will attract dirt (hence the night before recommend so it dries).

[Dealing with rust on a steel frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/478/dealing-with-rust-on-a-steel-frame)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about it too much, the rust will be worn away over time as you use them. For the future though, you could dry the pedals off after wet rides and periodically apply a small amount of light lubricant to the springs, etc.